# Resize float32 array with K-nearest neighbour in the same way as scipy.misc.imresize or tf.image.resize

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, scipy, image-resizing

I am to create a network using much of the same characteristics as pix2pix: https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow.

My adjustment is that I will not be using images, but matrices with **float32** values. This introduces a lot of problems and there is a lot to rewrite. Most of the code can easily be rewritten, but I've encountered a problem.

The network has a separable convolutional layer where the image is resized using `tf.image.resize`. This function uses different resize methods, such as K-Nearest Neighbors, and I don't want to loose that feature. Both `scipy.misc.imresize` and `tf.image.resize` are limited to int values and does not support any higher than uint16. If I were to transform the data to said formats, I will loose precision.

***Is there a way to create this efficiently in numpy (or any equivalent) supporting float32?***

Sorry for not introducing any code, but the problem more or less explains itself without (I hope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using  **scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom**. This works for float number images.
Use it as below:

**image = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(image, 0.5)**

Comment: This is a nice solution. I did not find this when I had the problem, so I ended up creating my own convolution function with filters defined in such a way that it created something similar to K-nearest.

It turns out that it is easier to simply use tf.conv with predefined filters. That way, the backprop will not update the weights and the conv layer only operates as an upscaling layer.